# Ajax + variable undefined

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a simple js function where I am passing number of iterations. 
This works for 1 iteration if it is more than 1 it say undefined in alert.
How can I store the test_iterations inside ajax function.

```
function _startTest(test_iterations) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?start=1',
      success: function(data) {
        $('.results').append('<p>Test #' + test_number +' ' + data + ' ms</p>');
        $('.results').scrollTop(10000);

        test_results.push(data);
        alert("_startTest" + test_iterations);

        if(test_number >= test_iterations) {
            end_tests(test_iterations);
        }

        test_number++;
      }
    });

}
```

Comment: :I suppose this is the working code you have posted.And test_iterations seems to be a variable that holds some int value.How can it come as undefined if the value is more than 1.I tested with a dummy function but the variables you define inside the function should alert the correct value inside the success function

Comment: Yes I got I had to define a global variable since I am calling this function in another function which gets value dynamicaly.. Thanks it works now.

Comment: no problem Vinod. probably the sender of the function does know what the next value is. It is what closure/scope is about. A variable inside a function doesnt know anything about another variable outside its scope. More reading: (http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the question but have you tried putting a var outside the function? Seems like you've been doing them with `test_number`

```
var iteration_count = 0;   // here
function _startTest(test_iterations) {
    iteration_count++;    // here
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?start=1',
      success: function(data) {
        $('.results').append('<p>Test #' + test_number +' ' + data + ' ms</p>');
        $('.results').scrollTop(10000);

        test_results.push(data);
        alert("_startTest" + iteration_count); // use this value instead
        if(test_number >= test_iterations) {
            end_tests(test_iterations);
        }
        test_number++;    
      }
    });

}
```